# Spring Oauth2 For Twitter Doesn't Remember Login

Tags: spring-security, twitter, oauth-2.0, twitter-oauth

I am trying to complete the Oauth2 authorisation flow for a Twitter App, using Spring Boot Oauth2.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Here are my settings in Spring:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          twitter:
            clientId: blah
            clientSecret: blah
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            client-authentication-method: none
            redirect-uri:  https://example.com/login/oauth2/code/twitter
            scope: tweet.read,users.read
        provider:
          twitter:
            authorizationUri: https://twitter.com/i/oauth2/authorize    
            tokenUri:  https://api.twitter.com/2/oauth2/token
```

The flow completes correctly, with the user logging in fine.   However, Twitter never seems to remember the user - each time I start the application I end up back at the "authorise" page, shown below.

[image: Twitter asking for authorization]

**Somehow, twitter believes each time that I need to authorise a new token.**

Is this the expected behaviour for Oauth2?   Does Twitter deliberately not remember that the user has authorised the app?

thanks,
Rob

Comment: I am havnig the same issue, did you find any solution for that ?

Comment: yes, I used oauth1.  My code is here: https://github.com/risk-first/twitter-bot/blob/master/tweetprint/src/main/java/org/riskfirst/tweetprint/auth/AuthConfig.java.